# "Disconnected" response from HttpClient.PostAync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

I'm trying to fix an issue with a legacy asp.net WebForms application written about 6 years ago.  I'll try to explain and hope that someone can see a fix.

Our application supports what we call an "API".  Really it's just a couple of pages intended to be displayed within the pages of our customers' websites.  We also provice a sample application that shows how to use it.

The sample app has some form fields for the caller to provide values.  When submitted, we create a string of HTML containing a  elelement with the  tag that

submit()'s the form on postgback.

Example:

...
form1.submit();

This method works successfully as long as the end user puts our domain in thier trusted sites.  Otherwise the user gets permission denied errors.    However, recently, we've had a couple customers refuse to add us to trusted sites and

want the issue fixed another way.

One approach I've tries is to use HttpClient.PostAsync() to do what the form/script above does but from the server side.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string address, MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue acceptType, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //client.BaseAddress = new Uri(address);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(acceptType);

        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(address, content).Result;

        return response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

}
```

It's called like this:

```
    string hash = GenerateHashValue();
    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> data = this.BuildPostData(hash);
    MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue acceptType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html");
    HttpResponseMessage msg = Post(this.GetPostTargetUrl(), acceptType, data);
    var task = msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    task.Wait();
    string result = task.Result;
    Response.Write(result);
    Response.End();
```

The response HTML is successfully written into the  but it's essentally "disconnected" - nothing works after that.  Normally, using the / method about uses can navigate in the iframe to other pages on our

site.Looking at it in fiddler, I see that some of the posts and redirects that I see when using the current / method is happeing and I get 404s for many of the javascript files coming from our site.

Can anyone suggest another approach in which I would not have XSS errors but a "connected" iframe?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: does it have to be a post method? if you are only passing relatevly small data piece you can use MIME of an image and add param to it... much like what Google Analyics is doing.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview

Comment: Yes, the requirements are for a POST.  There are literally hundreds of fileds that can be sent by the user in the request and we can't guarantee the size of the data the user will send.

But it's an interesting idea.  I'll look at for future applications.

Comment: BTW, here's the HTML that should have been in the Example from the original post:

<form id="form1" maction="http://www.ourdomain.com/somepage.aspx" method="post" target="frTarget" >
    <input type="hidden" id="key1" value="value1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="key2" value="value2" />
    ...
</form>

Comment: have you looked at JSONP, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP?

Comment: Yes,as well as some of the other XSS frameworks. However, we have some 3rd party integrators that use our "API" in thier apps.  We don't want to force them to use an particular framework.